# Eclipse Content Assist Struggles

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

Lately Eclipse's content assist feature has been giving me some frustration.
I recently changed my Auto Activation trigger so that the autocomplete box would appear whenever I start typing, rather than just after I type a period.
This is great most of the time but it has some annoying downsides. For example:[image: Eclipse autocompletes 'String' to android.R.string]

Eclipse autocompletes 'String' to android.R.string. This is very very annoying considering it changes "String" to "string" when I press space or enter. Why would I want that? android.r.string hasn't even been imported!

Here is what my content assist settings look like:[image]

Two desired solutions would be the following:

- Don't show proposals that don't match case (little 's' shouldn't match big 'S')
- Don't show proposals that I have not imported.

If anyone could help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: But I want Auto Activation to trigger on any letter as well as period, and by restoring defaults I lose that functionality.

Comment: I guess that's one option but ideally I would like to have it auto trigger, but do it correctly.

Comment: Yeah maybe I'm just expecting too much out of Eclipse haha. I guess you get what you paid for

Answer (score 0):

Try these:
1. Sort the proposals by relevance and not alphabetically. 
2. Hide proposals not visible in the invocation context (you have this one) and
3. Hide deprecated references

Comment: Changing to relevance fixed my "String -> string" problem but now it changes "int" to android.R.integer, which is equally if not more annoying.